# Integral of Laguerre Polynomial

Tags: integration, orthogonal-polynomials

Is there a general formula for integrals of the form
$$
\int_0^{\infty}dr \ r^l e^{-a r} L^{n}_{m} (b r)
$$
where $L^{n}_m$ is an associated Laguerre polynomial, $l \in \mathbb{Z}$, and $\text{Re }a > 0$? I found a formula here http://functions.wolfram.com/Polynomials/LaguerreL3/21/02/01/ however I did not understand the notation used (specifically the use of scubscripts on the coefficients in front of the sum). If someone knows the formula or could help me understand the one in the link above that would be very helpful!

Comment: Probably the thing to do is recognize that $L_0^\lambda(x)=1$, so you can insert $L_0^\lambda(br)$ into the integrand without changing it. That puts your integral in a form closer to those on that page. (However, it's not yet obvious to me how one gets a final result that isn't terrible.) Also, if you're wondering about the meaning of $(k)_n$, it's a so-called Pochammer symbol $(k)_n=(k)(k+1)\cdots(k+n-1)$.

Comment: Is this for hydrogenic wavefunctions by any chance?

Comment: @PlokavianNerveGas you guessed it. I'm trying to prove an identity involving operators acting on the ground state of the hydrogen atom.

Comment: Is $l$ an integer?

Comment: @Chappers yes sorry, i'll add that to my question.

Comment: http://dlmf.nist.gov/18.17#E40 gives the answer as a polynomial of degree at most $n$ (their notation) after writing out the hypergeometric function as its sum definition.

Comment: @Semiclassical It's not so bad because $n=0$ in the links notation. That collapses the second sum to just $k=0$ and $0$ Pochammer symbols are just $1$ so that entire part becomes $1$. Another coincidence is $\lambda=\beta$, so just write that part as a square of $(\lambda+1)_m$